# Compare long date format from preference

Tags: android, preferences

I can get file's Last Modified date and time, I would like to compare it with my last modified date and time from preference, but unfortunately it's always true.. Did I made a mistake?

```
 /* Get Last Update Time from Preferences */
    SharedPreferences prefs1 = getPreferences(0);
    long lastUpdateTime = prefs1.getLong("lastUpdateTime", 0);

    File file = new File(filePath);
    Date lastModDate = new Date(file.lastModified());
    long curMillis = lastModDate.getTime();

    /* Should Activity Check for Updates Now? */
    if ((lastUpdateTime) <= curMillis) {

        /* Save current timestamp for next Check */
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = getPreferences(0).edit();
        editor.putLong("lastUpdateTime", curMillis);
        editor.commit();

        do somthing....

    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `lastUpdateTime` would be always equal to `currMillis` because after your update you always set it equal to `currMillis`.

Your check should be -

```
if (lastUpdateTime < currMillis)
```

This will execute only if the file has been updated after the last check was performed because otherwise even if the file was not updated then also `currMillis` would be equal to `lastUpdateTime` so `(lastUpdateTime <= currMillis)`would evaluate to true but it should be false.